# Phoenix app won't start due to "Erlang node" error even after killing the process

Tags: phoenix-framework

When starting my phoenix app in production, I see this message:

> Protocol 'inet_tcp': the name my_app@127.0.0.1 seems to be in use by
> another Erlang node

However, when I run `ps aux | grep "my_app"` , It does not show me any -daemon process running.

If I change the name of the node in `vm.args` file, the application starts.
But, on next deployment, there is same issue and even if I kill process instead of doing `./bin/my_app stop` the error still shows.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I am using:
elixir : 1.11,
phoenix : 1.4.11,
distillery : 2.0

Comment: how about `ps aux | grep "elixir"`?

Comment: @LarryDrebes: That doesn't show the process either.